Catholicism: Do you have to confess specific instances or just kinds of sins?
When confessing mortal sins do you have to name specific instances or just the sin in general?  For example, if the sin was endangerment of human life and you did this in different ways on two completely unrelated occasions, would you have to describe them both or could you just say endangerment of human life?

I think that if you're of the mindset of trying to find the absolute minimum you have to do, then you probably aren't truly contrite.

@Acccumulation no. OP's question is completely reasonable. One can be afraid of revealing details to a priest. Endangerment of human life is a crime in most of the cases. In general priests must not share what they hear during confession. But it wouldn't be the first case if some priest would break this rule...

All mortal sins committed must be confessed not vaguely or generally (in genere), but in kind or "specifically" (in specie) and in number ("one by one", sigillatim):
Council of Trent, session 14 ch. 5:

it is manifest that priests could not have exercised this judgment without knowledge of the cause; neither indeed could they have observed equity in enjoining punishments, if the said faithful should have declared their sins in general only, and not rather specifically, and one by one. Whence it is gathered that all the mortal sins, of which, after a diligent examination of themselves, they are conscious, must needs be by penitents enumerated in confession

In your example, mentioning that your sins endangered human life (i.e., were against the 5th Commandment) is to state them generally. There is a huge difference between, for example, eating something unhealthy and killing someone, though these sins are both "endangerment of human life" (against the 5th Commandment). You have to mention your sins specifically.
You also have to mention the number. Killing one person is not the same as killing 40,000 people. Eating unhealthily for 365 days is not the same as eating unhealthily once a year. Etc.
